# Duplicate dialog in iOS app doesn't detect URLs from other sites

Tags: feature-request, bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, ios-app

I just erroneously closed [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364512/4751173) ([timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/364512/timeline)) as a duplicate of a [totally unrelated question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307784/4751173). How did that happen?

Well, I was using the Stack Exchange iOS app. I followed the link in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364512/please-help-undelete-this-question#comment564622_364512), linking to [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307784/295232). Hey, that's the same question, but on the app, it's kinda hard to notice you're on a *different site*; they all look the same. I clicked the 'share' link, copied the URL to the clipboard, went back to the Meta Stack Overflow question and voted to close the question as a duplicate. In the app, you then get a popup asking for the ID or URL of the duplicate target. I pasted `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307784/295232` and it was promptly closed (because of my [support](/questions/tagged/support) dupehammer) as a duplicate of question 307784 on Meta Stack Overflow.

This should not happen; if I paste a URL from another site, it should not try to extract a question ID from it and use it as a duplicate target. IMHO, this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but if TPTB think it isn't, please consider it as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).